# Django username in the User model can not be repeated

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create users in the django django.contrib.auth.models.User model but when I use a username which already exists in the database it will give me an error like:

```
{username: ["A user with that username already exists."]}
```

as an http response
How can I disable this in django so I can have many users with the same username
Thanks all.

Comment: Say you allow that, then what should happen if someone logs in with a duplicated username?

Comment: I use the email and password to log in

Comment: Then the email is the username, and you should use a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) which subclasses AbstractUser and sets [`USERNAME_FIELD'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) to "email".

Comment: so it is not a good practice at all???

Comment: @RodwanBakkar: well you can also monkey patch the `User`, but no... it is not good practice at all. Furthermore it means that people have to provide an email address, and some privacy-minding people do not like that at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman should I keep the username unique and use the first_name and last_name which they can be repeated in the database?

Comment: @RodwanBakkar if your use case needs the users to login using `email` and the `username` can be duplicated then you should create custom user model. Check out the django way of doing that: [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: You can either setup your own custom user model, but that comes together with some overhead like password reset form in django admin, and a custom object manager. That's what @DanielRoseman link is describing. You can also use an existing module which basically does that already for you. https://github.com/tmm/django-username-email is one of them, but there are many others as well.